# powershell Creating a loop that prints numbers divisible by 3, 5,15?

Tags: powershell

How can I fix this function so when I input a number like 100 I get the results like: 100 divisible by 5, 100 divisible by 15, and etc.
for ex:want it to print out like this

1
2
3- divisibleby3
4
5- divisibleby5
and so on and so on

```
function Print-Numbers-Weird ([int]$count) {

    for($i=0; $i -le $count; $i = $i + 1) {

        $isdivisibleby3 = $i % 3 -eq 0
        $isdivisibleby5 = $i % 5 -eq 0
        $isdivisibleby15 = $i % 15 -eq 0

       if($isdivisible) {
           Write-host $i "- Even"
        }
        else {
           Write-host $i "- Odd"
        }

        if($i -eq 3) 
        {
            Write-host "divisible by 3"
        }
        elseif($i -eq 5) 
        {
            Write-host "divisible by 5"
        }
        else {
            Write-host "divisible by 15"
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. Could you tell us what the specific issue you are running into is?

Comment: this sounds like the classic fizzbuzz assignment. have you looked at any of the VAST number of such posts for ideas? [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That's what thought too ...  one of the shortest I've seen: [FizzBuzz](https://dev.to/hf-solutions/solving-the-fizz-buzz-problem-in-powershell-4a9l) (short and still readable ...)

Comment: @Olaf - yep, that is one that i have seen. one thread over at r/powershell was about different ways to do fizzbuzz - and about code-golfing it. that was a fun [and mind-twisting] read. [*grin*]

Comment: thanks guys i'll check out fizzbuzz

Comment: really cool: [Fizz Buzz Test](http://wiki.c2.com/?FizzBuzzTest) ... the shortest Powershell version needs 62 charachters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it the other way around, is multiple of:

```
function Print-Numbers-Weird ([int]$count) {

    for($i=1;$i -le $count;$i++) {  
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Number=$i
            Even = $i % 2  -eq 0
            Odd  = $i % 2  -eq 1
            x3   = $i % 3  -eq 0
            x5   = $i % 5  -eq 0
            x15  = $i % 15 -eq 0
        }
    }
}

Print-Numbers-Weird 15 | ft -Auto
```

Sample output:

```
> Print-Numbers-Weird 15 | ft -Auto

Number  Even   Odd    x3    x5   x15
------  ----   ---    --    --   ---
     1 False  True False False False
     2  True False False False False
     3 False  True  True False False
     4  True False False False False
     5 False  True False  True False
     6  True False  True False False
     7 False  True False False False
     8  True False False False False
     9 False  True  True False False
    10  True False False  True False
    11 False  True False False False
    12  True False  True False False
    13 False  True False False False
    14  True False False False False
    15 False  True  True  True  True
```

Comment: That works thanks but they want it to print out for example this way                                                                      3- Divisibleby3                                                                                                                     4                                                                                                                                          5-Divisibley 5 and so on and so on

Comment: Just change the names in the [PSCustomObject] in front of the equal sign, if containing spaces you need to quote them.

Comment: change the name to what?

Comment: `3-Divisibly`, `5-Divisibly` ...?

Comment: i got it thanks it just want print the 15 i use the else function

Comment: function Print-Numbers-Weird ([int]$count) {

    for($i=1;$i -le $count;$i++) {  
     
      $isdivisibleby3 = $i % 3 -eq 0
      $isdivisibleby5 = $i % 5 -eq 0
      $isdivisibleby15 = $i % 15 -eq 0
      

      if($isdivisibleby3) {
       
        Write-host $i "- divisibleby3"
      }
      elseif($isdivisibleby5)
      {
        Write-host $i "- divisibleby5"
      }
      elseif($isdivisibleby15)
      {
        Write-host $i "- divisibleby15"
      }
      else{
      Write-host $i
      
     }
   }
}